# Indexof не распознает кириллицу

Tags: java, массивы, indexof

Есть небольшая проблема - нужно найти индекс элемента в стринговом массиве с помощью IndexOf. Вот кусок моего кода:

```
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("LS-1.csv"), ';');

    List<String[]> lines = reader.readAll();
    String[] lineHeader = lines.get(0);
    int index = Arrays.asList(lineHeader).indexOf("Сумма");
    System.out.println(index);
```

Собственно массив состоит из элементов - (За период;Учетный месяц;Дата документа;Создан;Тип;Расход;Сумма;Статус) и значит результат должен быть равен 6, но выдает -1

Comment: Выведите в консоль `lineHeader` и посмотрите, есть ли там "Сумма".

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался! Надо было в настройках IDEA поменять кодировку...

Answer (score 2):

В настройках Intellij IDEA в settings->editor->file encodings надо поменять кодировку на utf-8